# JavaScript/Jquery event for select where onchange reverts selection to default after performing action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a navigation dropdown whose onchange attribute calls a function which opens a child window and then resets the value for the dropdown to the default value.  I need to check which option was selected by the user but since the function reverts selected value to default I always get default value using any event handler. My select tag looks something like

```
<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdownId"  onchange="gotoMyFunction()">
        <option value="val1" selected="">text1</option>
        <option value="val2">text2</option>
        <option value="val3">text3</option>
        <option value="val4">text4</option>
</select>
```

and definition of gotoMyFunction()

```
function gotoMyFunction(){
        var selectedIndex  = $('mydropdownId').selectedIndex;
        var selectValue = $('mydropdownId').options[selectedIndex].value;
        switch (selectValue)
        {       
            case "val1":                
                val1Operation();                                
                $('mydropdownId').selectedIndex = 0;
                break;              
            case "val2":
                val2Operation();
                $('mydropdownId').selectedIndex = 0;
                break;          
            case "val3":                
                val3Operation();
                $('mydropdownId').selectedIndex = 0;
                break;                                              
            case "val4":                
                val4Operation();
                $('mydropdownId').selectedIndex = 0;
                break;              
            default:
                $('mydropdownId').selectedIndex = 0;
                // do nothing
        }    
        return true;
}
```

now the problem is that whenever I make a selection my drop down will always show **text1** as selected text because of the line `$('mydropdownId').selectedIndex = 0;` I am trying to create a recorder for the events happening on a website and I can only inject js through chrome plugin or chrome console.

**UPDATE**
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kunal19911/hy7fv5zc/26) link for my scenario  **please NOTE** HTML section of fiddle can't be updated to get the solution

Comment: Can you prepare a fiddle or codepen to illustrate the problem better?

Answer (score 1):

you made some minor mistakes here.

first of all, to select an element by ID, using jquery, you need to put a `'#'` in front of the name.
so you have to change

```
$('mydropdownId')
```

to

```
$('#mydropdownId')
```

to make this working.

the next thing is. .selectedIndex is a vanilla js property. when using jquery, you could use the `.prop()` function

```
$('#mydropdownId').prop("selectedIndex"); //using jquery .prop()
```

or if you prefer vanilla js, convert your jquery object to a js object.

```
$('#mydropdownId')[0].selectedIndex; //convert jquery object to js object
```

to finally create your 'click recorder' first you'd declare a global variable, to store your clicks. so above everything (within the dom ready function) you add the line:

```
var mySelValRecords = []; //this creates your array
```

for the simple recorder, you don't need a switch/case statement. so if you don't have 4 different functions, that do different things, depending on your selection, here's your all new select recorder function:

```
$("#mydropdownId").on("click", function(){ 
  mySelValRecords.push($(this).val()); //add the current selection to your array
  $(this).prop("selectedIndex", 0); //reset your selection
  //here you can check, the record of your clicks:
  console.log(mySelValRecords);
});
```

the downside of my solution is, that due to your reset to the first value of your list, there will never be a change event when choosing val1 - since it is already chosen. if you use the click event instead, val1 will be added on every click into the dropdown box, which may also result in unwanted content in the click recorder array...

so if you also want to record val1 clicks, you could use js to insert a new default option into the select box:

```
var defaultOptionElem = $("<option></option>") //create a new option element
    .val("default") //add a value to the element
    .prop("selected", true) // set this element to 'selected'
    .text("default"); //enter text to be shown in the dropdown
//prepend this as first element into your select box:
$("#mydropdownId").prepend(defaultOptionElem);
```

now, after every click, the default will be shown again and you can record all clicks from val1 to val4.
check http://jsfiddle.net/ztjad9o1/1/ for a working example

Comment: Hi I don't have access to html code of the application but it is working fine and yes that is the problem no matter what I use I always get val1. To avoid this I tried adding event to option which doesn't work with javascript. So I tried jquery to add event to option but for some reason that also didn't work

Comment: updated the answer. check out the linked fiddle and if it solves your issue. if this is not what you need, you have to get more concrete on your problem.

Comment: thanks for your help but that won't work because I don't have access to existing html and script. I have created a jsfiddle that describes my scenario. Please not that html section can't be updated [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kunal19911/hy7fv5zc/27/)